# Scope of a variable from Form to Class Module VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Form UserForm1 having two command buttons command 1 and command 2. The variable var = 1 when command1 is pressed and var=2 if command 2 is pressed. Var is a global variable in UserForm1. expDate and textRecDate are two textboxes in UserForm1

I have a class module clsMod and I am trying to do something like this

```
If UserForm1.var= 1 Then 
    UserForm1.expDate.Text = SelectedDate
If UserForm1.var= 2 Then 
    UserForm1.textRecDate.Text = SelectedDate
```

I want to extend the scope of var to the class module. Is there a way I can do that.

thanks

Comment: How is var declared?  The best approach would be to create it as a property on the form.  You should also add properties for expDate and recDate if you want to make your solution robust.

Comment: Var is declared as a Global Declaration in UserForm1 as an integer

Comment: yes. It is declared as Public

Comment: So what happens?  If you're seeing an error, what is it?

Comment: Compile error. Method of data member not found on UserForm1.var

Comment: You'll need to show all the relevant code (you should update your question with this)

Comment: You must have var declared as public at the VERY top of the userform module AND outside of any procedures.

Comment: Why are all these VBA questions tagged VB6??

Comment: @BobRiemersma I removed the VB6 tag from this one (easily done through the edit button)

Comment: @MarkJ Yes I know but it doesn't seem to be stemming the abuse any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to "extend" the scope - you want to *restrict* the scope to the Form level and then use `Public` methods to access/control the form.

eg - In UserForm1...

```
Private Var As Integer

Public Function GetVar() As Integer
    GetVar = Var
End Function

Public Sub SetTextRecDate(d as Date)
    textRecDate.Text = SelectedDate
End Sub
```

And in clsMod..

```
If UserForm1.GetVar = 2 Then 
    UserForm1.SetTextRecDate(SelectedDate)
    'The line above may actually want to be...
    'UserForm1.SetTextRecDate SelectedDate
    'VBA is strange about parenthesised arguments
Endif
```

etc etc

Oh and if the naming is not just for demonstration / example purposes please don't get in the habit of calling your buttons `Command1` and `Command2` and your variables `Var` :D ...